# PHP Mailer Script Not Printing Variables In Email

Tags: php, sendmail

The issue I am having is in the message portion of the email. The email sends just fine, the outline is there but no name email or message is printed from the variable. I can't seem to see what the issue is. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php session_start();
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$text=$_POST['text'];
$to= 'noreply@noreply.com';
$subject = 'Request';
$message='Hello, my name is:' . $name . "\r\n" . 'My Email is: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'My Message is: '. $text;
$headers = 'From: Request' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: noreply@noreply.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo 'Mail Sent';
?>
```

Comment: Echo the variables after you receive via POST and see if there is anything.

Comment: I tried this and there is not, however the URL shows the data is coming forward to the script

Comment: http://somedomain.com/mailer.php?name=test&email=test%40test.com&message=Message this is the url minus the real domain only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment you are passing the data as query string not as payload in the POST. SO change

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$text=$_POST['text'];
```

to

```
$name=$_GET['name'];
$email=$_GET['email'];
$text=$_GET['text'];
```

And should work !

Comment: For posting the data which is better you can define your form as `<form method="POST" action="page.php">`

Comment: Yes thank you, I just realized it was missing. Will accept answer as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

You sent form using `GET` method, data are in `$_GET`:

```
<?php 

session_start();

$name  = $_GET['name'];   // here
$email = $_GET['email'];  // here
$text  = $_GET['text'];   // here
$to    = 'noreply@noreply.com';
$subject = 'Request';
$message='Hello, my name is:' . $name . "\r\n" . 'My Email is: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'My Message is: '. $text;
$headers = 'From: Request' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: noreply@noreply.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo 'Mail Sent';
?>
```

To use your current script version, just change `method` attribute in `form` to post, like `<form method=post ...>`